# Can't deserialize json into map of objects after REST request

Tags: java, json, rest

I have got my json that server responds me:

```
    {
    "clients": {
        "0": {
            "id": 12370691,
            "fio": ""
        },
        "2": {
            "id": 12384782,
            "fio": "name2"
        },
        "3": {
            "id": 12389624,
            "fio": "Name3"

        }
    }
}
```

And I have got pojos due to jsons.

First Pojo contains map of objects

```
    @Data
public class GetClientsResponse {
    @JsonProperty("clients")
    Map<String, ClientResponse> clientMap;

    public List<ClientResponse> getListOfValues() {
        if (Objects.nonNull(this.clientMap)) {
            return this.clientMap.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

And ClientResponse class

```
    @Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ClientResponse {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int clientId;
    @JsonProperty("fio")
    private String fullName;
}
```

And I have got next error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400). JSON
>   parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap
>   out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY
>   token at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2a8f551b; line: 1,
>   column: 12] (through reference chain:
>   com.lineup.flatsender.model.dto.response.avers.getclinets.GetClientsResponse["clients"])
>   Blockquote

Could anybody explain what the problem? Cause it worked 1 month ago and I had no problems.
I'm using import org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations;

Answer (score -1):

Has the service changed recently? A [400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) response suggests that the server cannot understand your request.

Can you post the actual JSON you get back? The error suggests that you are getting back something with a JSON array but what you post doesn't show an array

Answer (score -1):

`JsonMappingException: out of START_ARRAY token` exception is `thrown` by Jackson object mapper as it's expecting an `Object {}` whereas it found an `Array [{}]` in response.

So may be response from webservice is changed and your clients data is now returned as Array instead of object.

Comment: Please do post the reason why answer is being downvoted, so that I can improve on it.